# how to increase Oracle SQL database or web service performance?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, webserver

I got a task to increase Oracle SQL database or web service performance. The web service required billions of data from the Oracle SQL database. Web service needs to populate those billions of data for each startup. Those data is mostly read-only and very rarely need an update or write data.

It is a very old codebase. That is why the solution was done in a way that it loads all data in memory to increase the performance. That is why it is slowing down development. It is like the first launch takes 30+ minutes. If for some reason those in-memory cached data becomes corrupted, I have to reload data from the database. It means another 30+ minutes waiting.

My task is to update this process. I have the flexibility to change the SQL database to something else that could help to speed up this process. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is better suited to advert for a short-term consultancy gig than a StackOverflow question. Way too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use MySQL. From my knowledge, MySQL has no limitation for the size of the database. I've attached a comparison you can look at between MySQL and Oracle. [Comparison](https://db-engines.com/en/system/MySQL%3BOracle)

Comment: It will still require to load all data at once in memory. I am googling to find any solution. I found Redis could be helpful in such a case.  But I have no much knowledge other than  Redis is key-value type database.

Comment: I'm not sure what that comparison is supposed to show; it doesn't refer to limits (which are [here for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limits.html) and [here for Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/database-limits.html)). I don't see how any of that relates to the question though?